# Dependent lookup in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, related-list

From the VF developer guide I'm learning how to create a related list in Visualforce. I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to filter a related list other than by using Visualforce?
2. Is it possible to use dependent lookups in Visualforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As far as I know there is now way to filter related lists other than Visualforce. There are some apps on appexchange to do so but they are not free.
2. It is possible to use dependent lookups in Visualforce it is also mentioned in the docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_dependent_lookups.htm&language=en)

Comment: Thanks, I've been googling myself for hours and I must assume you are right about the related list filtering. Still hard to believe though